# Documentation inside Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ide, xamarin-studio

I would like to have some documentation inside Xamarin Studio. It would be helpful to see the documentation of the .NET framework methods or the documentation of the iOS methods.

Is there any way to enable this? Or some way to hack it in there myself?

Answer (score 3):

**Help** - **API Documentation** will open MonoDoc.

MonoDoc will give you documentation on the .NET Base Class Library.

On the Mac it will also give you the option to merge the iOS documentation from Apple.

Comment: This does not seem to display the documentation inside Xamarin Studio though. Is there a way to see the appropriate documentation when I hover over methods, properties, ...?

Comment: When you hover over methods and properties you will not see full documentation. Instead you will see information taken from .xml files if they exist. This is not as detailed as the monodoc documentation.